# Background color not changing in ionic nav-bar

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have applied a background color in ionic nav-bar but no effect is shown in the nav-bar. Instead the nav-bar appears white. Please what could be wrong?

```
<ion-nav-bar style="background-color: #151B54" class="nav-title-slide-ios7">
    <!-- sets the header title -->
    <!-- sets the color bar of the header -->
    <ion-nav-back-button style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 3px; color:white; background-color: #151B54" class="button-icon"></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: Can you show me a fiddle of it?

Comment: try `.bar-energized.bar.bar-header{background:#151b54;}`

Comment: @Claudios you can not create ionic project on fiddle

Comment: This should be applied in my css file. I have tried it and it is not actually working... @Ved

Comment: @AndreaRobinson Yea my bad. Ionic uses its precompiled CSS but you can also add your own custom CSS using SASS. So better you need to know and understand SASS. I found this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html) for you.

Comment: try to find this directory on your project. `www/lib/ionic/scss` and try to locate `_variables.scss` from ther try to change the css style.

Comment: See this style.css http://plnkr.co/edit/95iF9CiVa15YJU4XE5Rf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The class `class="nav-title-slide-ios7"` might be overiding your style.
check the css file for that particular class.